# Como podria hacer que el usuario pueda ingresar los siguientes datos solo en una linea no como en el codigo y validarlo?

Tags: c

```
do{
    do{
        printf("Punto 1 A\n"); //X1
            scanf("%d",&a1);
            if(a1<0 || a1>10000)
            {
                printf("\nError el Numero Debe ser mayor a 0 y menor a 10.000\n");
            }
    }while(a1<0 || a1>10000);

    do{
        printf("Punto 2 A\n"); // Y1
            scanf("%d",&a2);
            if(a2<0 || a2>10000)
            {
                printf("Error el Numero Debe ser mayor a 0 y menor a 10.000\n");
            }
    }while(a2<0 || a2>10000);

    do{
        printf("Punto 1 B\n"); //X2
            scanf("%d",&b1);
            if(b1<0 || b1>10000)
            {
                printf("Error el Numero Debe ser mayor a 0 y menor a 10.000\n");
            }
    }while(b1<0 || b1>10000);

    do{
        printf("Punto 2 B\n"); //Y2
            scanf("%d",&b2);
            if(b2<0 || b2>10000)
            {
                printf("Error el Numero Debe ser mayor a 0 y menor a 10.000\n"); 
            }
    }while(b2<0 || b2>10000);
```

Comment: Te sugiero modificar el titulo, para que tu consulta tenga una mejor acogida. Aquí una guía de como hacerlo: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3574/t%C3%ADtulos-de-baja-calidad-en-preguntas?cb=1

Answer (score 0):

Disculpa, no entiendo bien tu pregunta. Lo que queres hacer es ingresar a1, a2, b1 y b2 en una misma linea y sin validar?

En caso de que sea asi bastaria con hacer lo siguiente:

- scanf("%d %d %d %d",&a1,&a2,&b1,&b2);

Procura ingresar un espacio entre cada elemento ingresado para que se almacene en la variable siguiente.

Espero que te sirva y si no es así te pido disculpas.

Answer (score 0):

.Si tienes definido la cantidad de valores, podrías pedirlos en un vector a través de un ciclo for. Crea una función donde captures y valides tus datos (veo que la condición para todos es la misma) así te ahorras varias lineas de código.